# Linq Query Returns Duplcates After Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, linq

I have table1 and table2 both have unique records and I need to left outer join to get DESCR from table2.

**table1:**

```
ID
SUBJECT
CATALOG_NBR
...
```

**table2:**

```
SUBJECT
CATALOG_NBR
DESCR
...
```

However after left outer join, I get double records. I tried groupby and still returns duplicates. Below is my query:

```cs
IQueryable<joinedTable> qry = (from a in db.table1
    join b in db.table2 on 
        new { SUBJECT=a.SUBJECT, CATALOG_NBR=a.CATALOG_NBR } equals
        new { SUBJECT = b.SUBJECT, CATALOG_NBR = b.CATALOG_NBR } 
    into ab from x  in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new joinedTable()
    {
        ID=a.ID,
        SUBJECT=a.SUBJECT,
        CATALOG_NBR=a.CATALOG_NBR,
        DESCR=x.DESCR
    }
    .GroupBy(a=>a.ID)
    .Select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault())
    .AsQueryable();
```

What is the problem in my query? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of new {SUBJECT=a.SUBJECT, CATALOG_NBR=a.CATALOG_NBR } use new {a.SUBJECT, a.CATALOG_NBR }.  Linq doesn't know how to compare with a named object.  Are both Subject and Catalog strings?

Comment: Thanks. yes. They are strings. I tried your way but it still returns duplicates.

Comment: You are having duplicate IDs?  You should only have one of each ID.  Looks like you are missing a parenthesis before the GroupBy : }).GroupBy(a=>a.ID).Select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault()).AsQueryable();

Comment: the ID field is unique integer in table1. Table2 does not have ID field.

Comment: So you can get <id,subject,CATALOB_NBR> :   <123,math, Math101> and <124,math, Math101>

Comment: I found out the problem is both tables have TITLE fields that I need to join them too. But the datatype in table1 in string and datatype TITLE in table2 is text and when I join SUBJECT, CATALOG_NBR and TITLE, it throws error "The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator." Now the problem becomes how to join two tables with different datatypes.

Comment: You can make the text a string : string.Join("", b.TITLE)  Note : I'm joining with an empty string which will take a character array an turn into a string.

Comment: ERROR "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." when I use string.join("",b.TITLE).

Comment: GTry : string.join("",b.TITLE.ToArray())

Comment: Error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join[Char](System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Char])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @jdweng Note that `new { a.SUBJECT }` and `new { SUBJECT = a.SUBJECT }` generate the exact same `Expression` tree.

Answer (score 0):

So the rows of Table1 and Table2 have an  Subject and a CatalogNr. And you want the "Rows of Table1, each with the zero or more Rows of Table2 that have the same value of Subject and CatalogNr"

Whenever you want items with their zero or more subitems, like Customers with their Orders, Schools with their Students, Table1Rows with their Table2Rows, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netcore-3.1).

```
var result = dbContext.Table1Rows.GroupJoin(dbContext.Table2Rows,

    table1Row => new
    {
        Subject=table1Row.SUBJECT,
        CatalogNr=table1Row.CATALOG_NBR
    },
    table2Row => new
    {
        Subject=table2Row.SUBJECT,
        CatalogNr=table2Row.CATALOG_NBR
    },

    // parameter ResultSelector: take each row of Table1 and the zero or more matching
    // matching rows of Table2 to make one new:
    (table1Row, table2Rows) =>  new
    {
        Id = table1Row.Id,
        Subject = table1Row.SUBJECT,
        CatalogNr = table1Row.CATALOG_NBR,
        
        Table2Descriptions = table2Rows.Select(table2Row => table2Row.DESCR).ToList(),
    });
```

In words:

- From every row in Table1, make one new object that contains the Subject and CatalogNr of the row.
- From every row in Table2, make one new object that contains the Subject and CatalogNr of the row.
- For every row in Table1, and all zero or more matching rows of Table2, make one new object, containing several properties of the row from table1, and a property Descriptions that is the list of all DESCRIPTION values of the matching table2 rows.

"Customers with their Orders" feels more natural then repeated combinations of [Customer 1, Order 1] [Customer 1, Order 2] [Customer 2, Order 3] etc. Anoter advantage of a GroupJoin is that the data of each Customer is transferred only once.

One major difference: with a Left Outer Join, you won't get the Customers that have no Orders. With a GroupJoin you will have every Customer, even if they don't have Orders. If you don't want that, add a simple where:

```
// keep only the table1 items that have at least one matching table2 item
.Where(groupJoinResult => groupJoinResult.Descriptions.Any())
```

And if you really want a flattened left outer join, use SelectMany. Personally I think there is no proper reason to do this.